# Django Admin - Custom Action with forms

Tags: html, django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm attempting to build a custom admin action. When users trigger this action, it should open a new window featuring a dropdown. They'll choose an option, and upon submission, the selected value will update multiple rows. Currently, I've managed to create this functionality, but I'm encountering an issue. When the form submits and redirects back to the admin interface, the selected value isn't present in the request's POST data.

**model.py:**

```html
class Intervencao(models.Model):
  ....
  responsavel = models.ForeignKey(Responsavel, blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE,verbose_name="Responsavel")
  .....



class Responsavel(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField("Responsável", max_length=200)
```

**admin.py:**

```html
  class IntervencaoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
 ....

     def assign_all_view(self, request, queryset):
        form = AssignResponsavelForm(request.POST or None)

        print("POST data:", request.POST)  # Debug: Print the entire POST data
        print("new_responsavel_id:", request.POST.get('new_responsavel'))  # Debug: Print the new_responsavel_id
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.is_valid():
                new_responsavel = form.cleaned_data['new_responsavel']
                selected_items = form.cleaned_data['selected_items']

                # Debug print statements
                print("New Responsável ID:", new_responsavel.id)
                print("Selected Items:", selected_items)

                Intervencao.objects.filter(pk__in=selected_items).update(responsavel=new_responsavel)

                # Debug message
                print("Responsável updated successfully")

        context = {
            'form': form,
            'queryset': queryset,
        }
        return render(request, 'admin/assign_all_view.html', context)
      actions = [assign_all_view]
```

**form.py**

```html
class AssignResponsavelForm(forms.Form):
    new_responsavel = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Responsavel.objects.all(), label="Novo Responsável")
    selected_items = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Responsavel.objects.all(), widget=forms.MultipleHiddenInput())
```

**assign_all_view.html**

```html
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <div class="module">
    <h2>Trocar de Responsável</h2>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="Trocar Responsável" class="default" />
    </form>
  </div>
{% endblock %}
```

**assign_all_view.html(already rendered)**

```html
<form method="post">
      <input type="hidden" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="o4k5jRUaryzHGXSeyQhAsKQ7WadDQusxRjg5p3HB2R0dRCV96kCzFToPZK6puMWO">
      <ul class="errorlist nonfield"><li>(Campo oculto selected_items) Este campo é obrigatório.</li></ul>
<ul class="errorlist"><li>Este campo é obrigatório.</li></ul>
<p><label for="id_new_responsavel">Novo Responsável:</label> <select name="new_responsavel" required="" id="id_new_responsavel">
  <option value="" selected="">---------</option>

  <option value="1">Responsavel 1</option>

  <option value="2">Responsavel 2</option>

</select></p>
      <input type="submit" value="Trocar Responsável" class="default">
    </form>
```

[image: Selecting the action]

[image: Select the new value]

[image: Logs]

As depicted in the screenshots, after selecting the custom action, a new page opens where we choose a new 'responsavel' option. However, upon returning to the admin page, the data is missing from the POST.